# How to select last option on dynamic list using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium

How to select last option on dynamic list Using Selenium and Java if I have a list with option that going to expend with new options every time.

List options WebElement examples:

```
//div[@id='transaction-history-view']/div[@id='accordion']/div[1]/div[@role='tab']//a[@role='button']
//div[@id='transaction-history-view']/div[@id='accordion']/div[2]/div[@role='tab']//a[@role='button']
//div[@id='transaction-history-view']/div[@id='accordion']/div[3]/div[@role='tab']//a[@role='button']
//div[@id='transaction-history-view']/div[@id='accordion']/div[4]/div[@role='tab']//a[@role='button']
```

Answer (score 2):

See if this works. Get all the options in the list and size()-1 will get the last index to select the last element.

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("your xpath for select element")));
List<WebElement> allOptions = select.getOptions();
int index = allOptions.size();
select.selectByIndex(index-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example I wrote this:

```
String xpathLastDiv = "(//div[@id='transaction-history-view'] /div[@id='accordion'] /div)[last()]"
String xpathLastButton = xpathLastDiv + "/div[@role='tab'] //a[@role='button']";
            
WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); //seconds
            
WebElement lastButton = webDriverWait.until(
                            ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(
                                By.xpath(xpathLastButton)
                            )
                        );

lastButton.click();
```